# Using fileDownload with an image

Tags: primefaces, download, graphicimage

I am using this code:

```
<p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false">                          
<p:fileDownload value="#{supplierFileController.fileroute()}" />                      
</p:commandLink>
```

Works great. The only thing is that I shows a normal link. I want to use it with an image instead. 
Something like this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{supplierFileController.destroy}">
<h:graphicImage title="Delete"   value="/image/image.png"/>                                               
</h:commandLink>
```

I have tried some combinations, but I havent been able to make it work.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
<p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">
```

Here a list of all available jquery Icons

[jQueryUI Icons Cheatsheet N#1](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html) (click on `Toggle text` to get all the names of the icons)

[jQueryUI Icons Cheatsheet N#2](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/)

Second option would be

```
<p:commandLink 
   styleClass="myDeleteBtnClass"
   id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false"
</p:commandLink>
```

try this class

```
.myDeleteBtnClass{ background-image: url('../resources/image/someImage.png'); }
```

Third Option would be

```
<h:commandLink action="#{supplierFileController.destroy}">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/image.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```

note that `images` folder should be located under the `WebContent\resources`  (take a look a this [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/))